# How to call function witch returning value is datasource for Material Table?

Tags: reactjs, material-table

So I have Material Table component witch get it's data from function that get's it with filter from database. Now the problem is that I have props that should re-render that table but that won't happen. I can't simple call that function when needed. I have tried using the references but it wont help or I just can't do it. Code is like:

```js
const ajax = (params) => {
    .
    .
    .
    return {
       data: result.data
    }
}

return (<>
    <MaterialTable data={ajax}>
</>
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That reference thing works fine:

```
import React from 'react'
const tableRef = React.createRef
const App = (props) => {
  tableRef?.current.onQueryChange()
  const ajax = (params) => {
    .
    .
    .
    return data
  }
  return (MaterialTable data={ajax} tableRef={tableRef}...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you try to pass the ajax returned value to state?

```
state = {
  data: [],
};
const ajax = async (params) => {
  const data = await fetch("endpoint")
    .then(res =>{this.setState({data: })})
    .catch(err => {
      //error handler
    });
}
render(){
  return(
    <MaterialTable data={this.state.data}/>
  )
}
```

let me know how my code works. or try to share your full code here

Comment: Yes I tried that already. Also tried this: const tableRef = React.createRef();
    if(tableRef.current){
        tableRef.current.onQueryChange();
    }